# CUDA: Host memory pointers not copied to device memory

Tags: cuda

we have the following struct defined

```
typedef struct PurchaseOrder
{ 
  char*   Value1;
  double  Value2; 
  double* Value3;
  int     Value3Length;

  __device__ int GetValue3Length() { return Value3Length; }
  __device__ double GetValue3(int i) { return Value3[i]; }
  __device__ void SetValue3(int i, double value) { Value3[i] = value; }
};
```

The PurchaseOrder data (array of structs) are marshalled from C# application into the following C dll function

```
int RunMonteCarlo(PurchaseOrder *hostPurchaseOrders, int length) {    
    PurchaseOrder *devPurchaseOrders; 
    // display the results
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    {
        //printf("\n\nAddress: %u",hostPurchaseOrders+i);            
        printf("\n\nIndex: %d", i);            
        printf("\nValue1: %s",(hostPurchaseOrders+i)->Value1);
        printf("\nValue2: %f",(hostPurchaseOrders+i)->Value2);

        for(int  j = 0; j < (hostPurchaseOrders+i)->Value3Length; j++)
        {
            printf("\nValue3[%d]: %fl", j, (hostPurchaseOrders+i)->Value3[j]);            
        }
    }    

    // allocate the memory on the GPU
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMalloc( (void**)&devPurchaseOrders, length * sizeof(PurchaseOrder) ) );

    // copy the array 'PurchaseOrder' to the GPU
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy( devPurchaseOrders, hostPurchaseOrders, length * sizeof(PurchaseOrder), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ) );    

    // Run the kernel code
    MonteCarloKernel<<<60,32>>>( devPurchaseOrders, length);

    // copy the array 'PurchaseOrders' back from the GPU to the CPU
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpy(hostPurchaseOrders, devPurchaseOrders, length * sizeof(PurchaseOrder), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost ) );    

    // free the memory allocated on the GPU
    HANDLE_ERROR( cudaFree( devPurchaseOrders ) );     

    return 0;
}

__global__ void MonteCarloKernel(PurchaseOrder *purchaseorders, long length) {
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

    while (i < length) 
    {
        purchaseorders[i].SetAAUS(1.11);

        for (int j=0; j < purchaseorders[i].GetValue3Length(); j++) 
        {
            //purchaseorders[i].SetValue3(j,1.0);
        }
        i += stride;
    }
}
```

The data are marshalled correctly as verified by the printf code at the beginning.

However, the Value3 (array of double) seems not copied into the device memory as the line purchaseorders[i].SetValue3(j,1.0) in the kernel crashes the application.

What should I do to solve it out?

When the application crashes, the console windows just closed. What debug technique I could use to get some meaningful messages?

Answer (score 2):

`Value1` and `Value3` are pointers. In `hostPurchaseOrders`, which refers to host data, these pointers are pointing to locations in host memory.

When you allocate device memory for `devPurchaseOrders` using `cudaMalloc`, the memory is only allocated for the structures and the pointers inside them. When you copy `hostPurchaseOrders` to `devPurchaseOrders`, you only copied the memory addresses in Value1 and Value3 fields. Since, they are pointing to some location in host memory, this location cannot be accessed successfully from the device.

The host memory pointers cannot be directly copied to device memory like you did above. You will need to manually allocate a device location for each host pointer, copy the values there from host to device and then set this location in the `Value1` and `Value3` pointers of the device structure.

This is extremely messy. Consider restructuring your host data, so that you can copy from host to device in a simple manner.